# two buttons are overlapping each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form in my ui(HTML page) where i have some input fields and a search button(submit),on clicking search wht i am doing is hiding the form and showing some content in a div tag (content is HTML table).That HTML table has a export button which is there to export the table content into a excel sheet.
but on clicking the search button of form the export button loaded first and the table lodes after that

like this

[image: after clicking search it loaded before the table]

here is my HTML form and after that form my div container which have table as well as export button

```
     <form id="formId" method="get">
        <div class="container">
            <h4>Start Date:</h4>
            <input  type="text" id="startdate" name="fromdate" width="276"
                placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" required onchange="checkDate()" />
            <h4>End Date:</h4>
            <input  type="text" id="enddate" name="todate" width="276"
                placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" required onchange="checkDate()"/>


            <h4>Outlets:</h4>
            <select id="all" name="outlet">
                 <option>ALL</option> 
                <c:forEach var="item" items="${obj.outlet}">
                    <option>${item}</option>
                </c:forEach>
            </select> 
         <div><br>
                </div>

            <div>
                <br>
 <button id="button" class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Search</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form> 
    <div id="tableContainer" class="container-fluid">
    <div id="tbl" ></div>

<button id="export">Export</button>


</div>
```

and here is my javascript by which i am making the ajax call

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#formId").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url : "URL",
            method : "GET",
            dataType : "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data : {
                   fromdate : $("#startdate").val(),
                   todate : $("#enddate").val(),
                   outlet : $("#all").val()

                 },

            success : function(data) {


//          console.log("test",tableValue);
            $("#formId").hide();
            var dataObj = formatData(data);
            addTable(dataObj);



        }

    });
```

this my code to initially hide the table

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
             //at beginning

             $('#tableContainer').hide();

             $('#button').click(function (e) {

               $('#tableContainer').show();
             });

             $("#export").click(function() {
                    $("#tbl").table2excel({
                        filename : "filenameSales.xls"
                    });
                });

             });
```

i just want that the export button should loaded after the table, here i am hiding form and after that showing all the data into new div tag.
how can i achieve that anyone have any idea please guide me.

this is the full code with json.by this code  i am manupulating the j

```
    data=[
      {
        "amount": 11750,
        "billdate": "2018-05-05",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS SARJAPURA ROAD"
      },
      {
        "amount": 11030,
        "billdate": "2018-05-05",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS SINGASANDRA"
      },
      {
        "amount": 11619,
        "billdate": "2018-05-05",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS SPICE GARDEN"
      },
      {
        "amount": 45229,
        "billdate": "2018-05-05",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "Chef Bakers Whitefield"
      },
      {
        "amount": 38239,
        "billdate": "2018-05-05",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS YELAHANKA"
      },
      {
        "amount": 7230,
        "billdate": "2018-05-06",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS ARAKERE"
      },
      {
        "amount": 14836,
        "billdate": "2018-05-06",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS AYYAPPA NGR"
      },
      {
        "amount": 13984,
        "billdate": "2018-05-06",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "Chef Bakers Bellandur"
      },
      {
        "amount": 1053,
        "billdate": "2018-05-06",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS CHANDAPURA"
      },
      {
        "amount": 16239,
        "billdate": "2018-05-06",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "Chef Bakers Doddanekkundi"
      },
      {
        "amount": 9575,
        "billdate": "2018-05-06",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS SIDDAPURA"
      },
      {
        "amount": 17965,
        "billdate": "2018-05-06",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS ECITY"
      },
      {
        "amount": 2644,
        "billdate": "2018-05-06",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS VYDEHI"
      },
      {
        "amount": 4250,
        "billdate": "2018-05-06",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "Chef Bakers Hennur Main Road"
      },
      {
        "amount": 17303,
        "billdate": "2018-05-06",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS KADUBEESANAHALLI"
      },
      {
        "amount": 15680,
        "billdate": "2018-05-06",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS COFFEE BOARD"
      },
      {
        "amount": 8035,
        "billdate": "2018-05-06",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "Chef Bakers Kaggadasapura"
      },
      {
        "amount": 4415,
        "billdate": "2018-05-06",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "Chef Bakers Koramangala"
      },
      {
        "amount": 8785,
        "billdate": "2018-05-06",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "Chef Bakers Marathahalli 1"
      },
      {
        "amount": 10425,
        "billdate": "2018-05-06",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "Chef bakers Marathahalli 2"
      },
      {
        "amount": 12625,
        "billdate": "2018-05-06",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "Chef Bakers Mahadevapura"
      },
      {
        "amount": 12340,
        "billdate": "2018-05-06",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS BEL LAYOUT"
      },
      {
        "amount": 12040,
        "billdate": "2018-05-06",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS MG ROAD"
      },
      {
        "amount": 13859,
        "billdate": "2018-05-06",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS NAGAWARA"
      },
      {
        "amount": 9125,
        "billdate": "2018-05-06",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS PRESTIGE SHANTHINIKETAN"
      },
      {
        "amount": 24780,
        "billdate": "2018-05-06",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS RR NAGAR"
      },
      {
        "amount": 27865,
        "billdate": "2018-05-06",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "Chef Bakers Kadugodi"
      },
      {
        "amount": 11285,
        "billdate": "2018-05-06",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS SARJAPURA ROAD"
      },
      {
        "amount": 3305,
        "billdate": "2018-05-06",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS SINGASANDRA"
      },
      {
        "amount": 12625,
        "billdate": "2018-05-06",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS SPICE GARDEN"
      },
      {
        "amount": 33766,
        "billdate": "2018-05-06",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "Chef Bakers Whitefield"
      },
      {
        "amount": 34300,
        "billdate": "2018-05-06",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS YELAHANKA"
      },
      {
        "amount": 6751,
        "billdate": "2018-05-07",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS ARAKERE"
      },
      {
        "amount": 12626,
        "billdate": "2018-05-07",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS AYYAPPA NGR"
      },
      {
        "amount": 33020,
        "billdate": "2018-05-07",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "Chef Bakers Bellandur"
      },
      {
        "amount": 450,
        "billdate": "2018-05-07",
        "counter": "Take Away",
        "outlet": "Chef Bakers Bellandur"
      },
      {
        "amount": 2215,
        "billdate": "2018-05-07",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS CHANDAPURA"
      },
      {
        "amount": 6518,
        "billdate": "2018-05-07",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "Chef Bakers Doddanekkundi"
      },
      {
        "amount": 11305,
        "billdate": "2018-05-07",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS SIDDAPURA"
      },
      {
        "amount": 11990,
        "billdate": "2018-05-07",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS ECITY"
      },
      {
        "amount": 11350,
        "billdate": "2018-05-07",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS VYDEHI"
      },
      {
        "amount": 5440,
        "billdate": "2018-05-07",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "Chef Bakers Hennur Main Road"
      },
      {
        "amount": 20707,
        "billdate": "2018-05-07",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS KADUBEESANAHALLI"
      },
      {
        "amount": 14155,
        "billdate": "2018-05-07",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS COFFEE BOARD"
      },
      {
        "amount": 5285,
        "billdate": "2018-05-07",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "Chef Bakers Kaggadasapura"
      },
      {
        "amount": 5404,
        "billdate": "2018-05-07",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "Chef Bakers Koramangala"
      },
      {
        "amount": 5200,
        "billdate": "2018-05-07",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "Chef Bakers Marathahalli 1"
      },
      {
        "amount": 13000,
        "billdate": "2018-05-07",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "Chef bakers Marathahalli 2"
      },
      {
        "amount": 20049,
        "billdate": "2018-05-07",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "Chef Bakers Mahadevapura"
      },
      {
        "amount": 10592,
        "billdate": "2018-05-07",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS BEL LAYOUT"
      },
      {
        "amount": 9934,
        "billdate": "2018-05-07",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS MG ROAD"
      },
      {
        "amount": 9803,
        "billdate": "2018-05-07",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS NAGAWARA"
      },
      {
        "amount": 13877,
        "billdate": "2018-05-07",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS PRESTIGE SHANTHINIKETAN"
      },
      {
        "amount": 42368,
        "billdate": "2018-05-07",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS PRITECH"
      },
      {
        "amount": 13173,
        "billdate": "2018-05-07",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS RR NAGAR"
      },
      {
        "amount": 26263,
        "billdate": "2018-05-07",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "Chef Bakers Kadugodi"
      },
      {
        "amount": 7250,
        "billdate": "2018-05-07",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS SARJAPURA ROAD"
      },
      {
        "amount": 3100,
        "billdate": "2018-05-07",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS SINGASANDRA"
      },
      {
        "amount": 9870,
        "billdate": "2018-05-07",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS SPICE GARDEN"
      },
      {
        "amount": 23093,
        "billdate": "2018-05-07",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "Chef Bakers Whitefield"
      },
      {
        "amount": 20805,
        "billdate": "2018-05-07",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS YELAHANKA"
      },
      {
        "amount": 4140,
        "billdate": "2018-05-08",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS ARAKERE"
      },
      {
        "amount": 11137,
        "billdate": "2018-05-08",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS AYYAPPA NGR"
      },
      {
        "amount": 33034,
        "billdate": "2018-05-08",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "Chef Bakers Bellandur"
      },
      {
        "amount": 700,
        "billdate": "2018-05-08",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS CHANDAPURA"
      },
      {
        "amount": 12351,
        "billdate": "2018-05-08",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "Chef Bakers Doddanekkundi"
      },
      {
        "amount": 12190,
        "billdate": "2018-05-08",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS SIDDAPURA"
      },
      {
        "amount": 13269,
        "billdate": "2018-05-08",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS ECITY"
      },
      {
        "amount": 10023,
        "billdate": "2018-05-08",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS VYDEHI"
      },
      {
        "amount": 5180,
        "billdate": "2018-05-08",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "Chef Bakers Hennur Main Road"
      },
      {
        "amount": 22279,
        "billdate": "2018-05-08",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS KADUBEESANAHALLI"
      },
      {
        "amount": 17543,
        "billdate": "2018-05-08",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS COFFEE BOARD"
      },
      {
        "amount": 11850,
        "billdate": "2018-05-08",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "Chef Bakers Kaggadasapura"
      },
      {
        "amount": 7634,
        "billdate": "2018-05-08",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "Chef Bakers Koramangala"
      },
      {
        "amount": 8175,
        "billdate": "2018-05-08",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "Chef Bakers Marathahalli 1"
      },
      {
        "amount": 13159,
        "billdate": "2018-05-08",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "Chef bakers Marathahalli 2"
      },
      {
        "amount": 21519,
        "billdate": "2018-05-08",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "Chef Bakers Mahadevapura"
      },
      {
        "amount": 7610,
        "billdate": "2018-05-08",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS BEL LAYOUT"
      },
      {
        "amount": 7634,
        "billdate": "2018-05-08",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS MG ROAD"
      },
      {
        "amount": 23463,
        "billdate": "2018-05-08",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS MANYATA TECH PARK"
      },
      {
        "amount": 14705,
        "billdate": "2018-05-08",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS NAGAWARA"
      },
      {
        "amount": 9020,
        "billdate": "2018-05-08",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS PRESTIGE SHANTHINIKETAN"
      },
      {
        "amount": 40225,
        "billdate": "2018-05-08",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS PRITECH"
      },
      {
        "amount": 11430,
        "billdate": "2018-05-08",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS RR NAGAR"
      },
      {
        "amount": 21596,
        "billdate": "2018-05-08",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "Chef Bakers Kadugodi"
      },
      {
        "amount": 7000,
        "billdate": "2018-05-08",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS SARJAPURA ROAD"
      },
      {
        "amount": 3050,
        "billdate": "2018-05-08",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS SINGASANDRA"
      },
      {
        "amount": 6705,
        "billdate": "2018-05-08",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS SPICE GARDEN"
      },
      {
        "amount": 29221,
        "billdate": "2018-05-08",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "Chef Bakers Whitefield"
      },
      {
        "amount": 24020,
        "billdate": "2018-05-08",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS YELAHANKA"
      },
      {
        "amount": 5410,
        "billdate": "2018-05-09",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS ARAKERE"
      },
      {
        "amount": 13660,
        "billdate": "2018-05-09",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "Chef Bakers Bellandur"
      },
      {
        "amount": 1073,
        "billdate": "2018-05-09",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS CHANDAPURA"
      },
      {
        "amount": 8995,
        "billdate": "2018-05-09",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "Chef Bakers Doddanekkundi"
      },
      {
        "amount": 13405,
        "billdate": "2018-05-09",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS SIDDAPURA"
      },
      {
        "amount": 14910,
        "billdate": "2018-05-09",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS ECITY"
      },
      {
        "amount": 9730,
        "billdate": "2018-05-09",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS VYDEHI"
      },
      {
        "amount": 4001,
        "billdate": "2018-05-09",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "Chef Bakers Hennur Main Road"
      },
      {
        "amount": 16252,
        "billdate": "2018-05-09",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS KADUBEESANAHALLI"
      },
      {
        "amount": 6490,
        "billdate": "2018-05-09",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "Chef Bakers Kaggadasapura"
      },
      {
        "amount": 6913,
        "billdate": "2018-05-09",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "Chef Bakers Koramangala"
      },
      {
        "amount": 13493,
        "billdate": "2018-05-09",
        "counter": "Fast Food",
        "outlet": "Chef Bakers Marathahalli 1"
      },
        ]

function formatData(data) {
    let toReturn = [];
    let dateWiseObj = {};
    let maxUniqueForOutlets = {};
    data.forEach(function (d) {
        if (!maxUniqueForOutlets[d["outlet"]]) {
            maxUniqueForOutlets[d["outlet"]] = [];
        }
        if (maxUniqueForOutlets[d["outlet"]].indexOf(d["counter"]) == -1) {
            maxUniqueForOutlets[d["outlet"]].push(d["counter"]);
        }

        if (!dateWiseObj[d["billdate"]]) {
            dateWiseObj[d["billdate"]] = {};
            dateWiseObj[d["billdate"]][d["outlet"]] = {};
            dateWiseObj[d["billdate"]][d["outlet"]][d["counter"]] = d;
        } else {
            if (!dateWiseObj[d["billdate"]][d["outlet"]]) {
                dateWiseObj[d["billdate"]][d["outlet"]] = {};
                dateWiseObj[d["billdate"]][d["outlet"]][d["counter"]] = d;
            } else {
                if (!dateWiseObj[d["billdate"]][d["outlet"]][d["counter"]]) {
                    dateWiseObj[d["billdate"]][d["outlet"]][d["counter"]] = d;
                }
            }
        }

    });



    return {
        dateWiseObj: dateWiseObj,
        maxUniqueForOutlets: maxUniqueForOutlets
    };
};


function addTable(dataObj) {
    let dateWiseObj = dataObj.dateWiseObj;
    let maxUniqueForOutlets = dataObj.maxUniqueForOutlets;
    let table = document.createElement("table");
    let thead = document.createElement("thead");
    let headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
    let th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = "Outlet";
    headerRow.appendChild(th);
    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = "Total";
    headerRow.appendChild(th);
    Object.keys(maxUniqueForOutlets).forEach(function (d) {
        th = document.createElement("th");
        th.innerHTML = d;
        th.colSpan = maxUniqueForOutlets[d].length + 1;
        headerRow.appendChild(th);
    });
    thead.appendChild(headerRow);

    headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = "Bill_____Date";
    headerRow.appendChild(th);
    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = "Counter";
    headerRow.appendChild(th);
    Object.keys(maxUniqueForOutlets).forEach(function (k) {
        th = document.createElement("th");
        th.innerHTML = "Total";
        headerRow.appendChild(th);
        maxUniqueForOutlets[k].forEach(function (d) {
            th = document.createElement("th");
            th.innerHTML = d;
            headerRow.appendChild(th);
        });
    });
    thead.appendChild(headerRow);
    table.appendChild(thead);


    let tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
    headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
    let completeTotal = 0;
    let outletandCounterWiseCompleteTotal = {};
    Object.keys(dateWiseObj).forEach(function (k) {
        let row = document.createElement("tr");

        let td = document.createElement("td");
        td.innerHTML = k;
        row.appendChild(td);


        grandTotal = 0;
        outletWiseTotal = {};
        Object.keys(maxUniqueForOutlets).map(function (d) {
            if (!outletandCounterWiseCompleteTotal[d])
                outletandCounterWiseCompleteTotal[d] = {};
            outletWiseTotal[d] = 0;
            if (dateWiseObj[k][d]) {
                Object.keys(dateWiseObj[k][d]).forEach(function (i) {
                    if (outletandCounterWiseCompleteTotal[d][i]) {
                        outletandCounterWiseCompleteTotal[d][i] += parseInt(dateWiseObj[k][d][i]["amount"] || "0");
                    } else {
                        outletandCounterWiseCompleteTotal[d][i] = parseInt(dateWiseObj[k][d][i]["amount"] || "0");
                    }
                    outletWiseTotal[d] += parseInt(dateWiseObj[k][d][i]["amount"] || "0");
                });
            }
            if (outletandCounterWiseCompleteTotal[d]["total"])
                outletandCounterWiseCompleteTotal[d]["total"] += outletWiseTotal[d];
            else
                outletandCounterWiseCompleteTotal[d]["total"] = outletWiseTotal[d];
            grandTotal += outletWiseTotal[d];
        });
        td = document.createElement("td");
        td.innerHTML = grandTotal;
        row.appendChild(td);

        Object.keys(maxUniqueForOutlets).map(function (d) {
            td = document.createElement("td");
            td.innerHTML = outletWiseTotal[d];
            row.appendChild(td);
            if (dateWiseObj[k][d]) {
                maxUniqueForOutlets[d].forEach(function (i) {
                    td = document.createElement("td");
                    td.innerHTML = dateWiseObj[k][d][i] ? dateWiseObj[k][d][i]["amount"] : "0";
                    row.appendChild(td);
                });
            } else {
                maxUniqueForOutlets[d].forEach(function (i) {
                    td = document.createElement("td");
                    td.innerHTML = "0";
                    row.appendChild(td);
                });
            }
        });
        tbody.appendChild(row);
        completeTotal += grandTotal;
        //console.log(outletWiseTotal);
    });

    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = "Total";
    headerRow.appendChild(th);
    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = completeTotal;
    headerRow.appendChild(th);

    Object.keys(maxUniqueForOutlets).forEach(function (d) {
        if (outletandCounterWiseCompleteTotal[d] && outletandCounterWiseCompleteTotal[d]["total"]) {
            th = document.createElement("th");
            th.innerHTML = outletandCounterWiseCompleteTotal[d]["total"];
            headerRow.appendChild(th);
        } else {
            th = document.createElement("th");
            th.innerHTML = 0;
            headerRow.appendChild(th);
        }
        maxUniqueForOutlets[d].forEach(function (i) {
            if (outletandCounterWiseCompleteTotal[d] && outletandCounterWiseCompleteTotal[d][i]) {
                th = document.createElement("th");
                th.innerHTML = outletandCounterWiseCompleteTotal[d][i];
                headerRow.appendChild(th);
            } else {
                th = document.createElement("th");
                th.innerHTML = 0;
                headerRow.appendChild(th);
            }
        });
    });

    thead.appendChild(headerRow);
    table.appendChild(tbody);
    let divContainer = document.getElementById("tbl");
    divContainer.innerHTML = "";
    divContainer.appendChild(table);
    table.classList.add("table");
    table.classList.add("table-striped");
    table.classList.add("table-bordered");
}
var dataObj = formatData(data);
addTable(dataObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `tableContainer` should be initially hidden, and when the table done loading, set it to visible. No need to try to do it on button level. The exact code would depend on what lib you use to create your table

@edit:
Oh, since you are doing it in pure Javascript and manipulate the DOM in this way,just add this at the end of `addTable`

```
$("#tableContainer").show();
```

And look for the place your code previously unhide the `tableContainer`. Since you hide it in `document ready`, there must be somewhere it got unhide in the code that was not in what you posted

@edit 2: Also delete

```
  $('#button').click(function (e) {

               $('#tableContainer').show();
             });
```

Comment: You should post the working code as example to make your answer more valuable.

Comment: look an edit is made to the post .. i am  doing as it is

Comment: I need the code that made the table itself. The name of the lib is enough. Basically the code inside addTable(dataObj);

Comment: @LoredraL i don't know what are you saying i am already doing it.

Comment: Dont show the container on button click event. Show it at the end of addTable

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would add a CSS class to a high level DOM element such as the BODY tag when the data has loaded to help trigger the style changes you desire. Doing it at such a high level like the body leaves scope for expansion in the future. So do that in the success function of your AJAX request as below:

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#formId").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url : "URL",
            method : "GET",
            dataType : "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data : {
                   fromdate : $("#startdate").val(),
                   todate : $("#enddate").val(),
                   outlet : $("#all").val()

                 },

            success : function(data) {


//          console.log("test",tableValue);

            $("body").addClass('data-loaded');
            var dataObj = formatData(data);
            addTable(dataObj);



        }

    });
```

Note I've also removed `$("#formId").hide();` as you could now use my new class to hide the button using CSS so `.data-loaded #formId {display none;}`. You could then do the opposite CSS for your table to make it appear when the body has that class.

It's also not great user experience to hide user controls like forms when they're used in this way. It would be better to keep your form visible, show the results immediately below and have a Search Again button which deletes any previous search results before performing a new search. This is obviously more work but your users will appreciate the extra effort for sure.

Comment: i got your point like you are saying, i should display the HTML table below the form there is no need to hide the form right?

Comment: Yeah I've built a lot of search results pages in my time and its always bad form to hide the controls. What if a user realises they've used the wrong start/end date and want to amend their results? Hiding the form would make that impossible. So make sure you have some JQuery/Javascript in place which resets your form back to an untouched state after a search and then you can add a Search Again button which just removes the .data-loaded class.

Comment: so how can this remove my overlapping of buttons problem?

Comment: Because you would hide your Export button with CSS by default and then show it when the body has the .data-loaded class. So the Export button would only show when the table is full with data and visible on screen.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?